# Run MySQL Command In Background - nohup

Tags: mysql, nohup, background-process

I need to run in background mode some mysql-query...
But how can i do this with `nohup`?

Standardly i do:

```
mysql -uroot -p
use SomeDb;
Select * from blablalba;
```

But how can i do this with launching in db process?
i do mysql importing with nohup, but how with query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysql -u [username] -p [database_name] -e "[sql_query]"
```

Example:

```
nohup mysql -u root -p somedb -e "select * from mytable" &
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this helped  However, I needed to enter a password after the command, so I did the following:

> ```
> $ nohup mysql -u [username] -p [database_name] -e "[sql_query]"
> Enter password:
> ```

Since I couldn't successfully run the command in the background, after entering the password at the prompt I closed my connection (by closing my remote console).  I opened up a new session and it ran.  It was a 3hr query with a spotty wireless connection, so this came in handy bigtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup mysql -u [username] -p[password] [database_name] -e "[sql_query]" &
```

Be sure to have the password follow the `-p` WITHOUT a space

Answer (score 0):

I was having some timeout issues with the above solutions for some reason, but using the `-c` option seemed to fix it (Note that this also includes setting a password and redirecting the standard output and errors to a certain path):

```
nohup bash -c "mysql -u my_user --password='my_password' -e \"use SomeDb;  Select * from blablalba;\"" > my_file_path 2>&1 &
```